# C# using minTime.ToUniversalTime is an hour out on a clients computer

Tags: c#, datetime

I don't know a great deal about this subject so forgive my daft question, I have a datagrid that shows the date and time a change was made to the database, it works fine on my PC but on my clients the time is +1 hour. Is this because I have used .ToUniversalTime instead of .ToLocalTime? Thanks for any help.

**Update:** I've just run the program on my XP machine instead of my Vista machine and the time is +1 hour on XP, the timezone, daylight savings and zone are all the same. Is this a .Net thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.ToUniversalTime()
```

gives you the current date time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).  In summary this is the current time (GMT) without any seasonal/regional changes.  Typically server applications use UTC for datetime storage as this gives a known baseline for users that may in different time zones.

As for a solution, well this depends on your application and how it is used.  You could store your dates as the current date from the users perspective and ignore UTC but you could run into problems if you have multiple users in different time zones.  Or you could store in UTC and then manage datetimes in the code per the current users locale.

For nothing more than curiosities sake, more info on UTC can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: All this said I have just noticed how old this question is, so the chances are this information is now useless to you :)